# memory allocated when launching jar via command line, but not if double clicked

Tags: java, windows, command-line, jar, jvm-arguments

I have a .jar file which represents a wrapper to launch another .jar file with some arguments for the JVM, as apparently there is no other way to do it. This wrapper builds up the command line arguments `java -jar <arg1> <arg2> ... MyJarFile.jar` based on the system architecture: invoking the 64 bit JVM (`-d64`) or not and setting the heap size via `-Xmx1280M` (max on a 32 bit system, from what I understood) or asking for 4 GB if it's a 64 bit architecture. Checking the Java version via `java -version` shows me that I have a 64 bit JVM running and checking the PATH in the environment variables confirms it. Now, everything is OK if I launch the wrapper via the command line. The actual .jar file is launched with an allocated 4GB of memory. If I double click the wrapper from Windows explorer, the actual .jar file is launched with the minimum (e.g., 247 MB) of memory. **Note** that I have also set the `-Xms512MB` in the command arguments, which apparently is ignored if launching the wrapper from the Windows UI. It is true, that on the machines that I experience the problem, both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Java are installed. Checking the Windows registry (regedit) under local machine/jarFile entry, I see that it is linked to the 32 bit version of the runtime environment. If I change it there, it works, but as soon as a java update is installed, the registry setting is reverted. Any ideas why this is happening? (I did not test on UNIX systems yet as the application is mainly used on Windows). Thank you.

Comment: May I ask why you are using a .jar file to pass jvm arguments? The more normal way would be to supply 2 scripts, a .bat script for windows and a .sh script for unix, and do this via a script.

Comment: I am using a wrapper as I am automatically exporting both the wrapper .jar and the actual .jar file when I build it (version control). So, to avoid modifying the .bat or .sh at hand every time. And it is OS/architecture independent. Plus, the users of the applications may have restrictions running those kind of scripts

Answer (score 0):

See an example with 2GB :

```
java -Xmx2g -jar <your-file>.jar
```

Hope it helps

Comment: ...really!? :/ I am not sure you actually understood the question. It's been a while ago since then anyhow, and I guess I've left it at the hand of administrators to make sure there is only one Java version installed on the machine which has to run the application.